# OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space when trying to create ArrayList

Tags: java, memory

I am trying to write a program which converts all G1 lines of a G code to lines which say `MOVX (x-coordinate of G1 command)`

Eg. `G1 X0.1851` should become `MOVX(0.1851)`

At the moment the program is just appending the text file that has been read and printing the new code below the old one in the same text file.

The problem is that when I try to create an array list of the number after the `X` in the `G-Code`, I get a problem with the memory in the heap space overflowing.

I have added a `clear()` statement after each iteration of a line of the `G-Code` to try to prevent the array list becoming larger and larger but it keeps overflowing.

Here is my code:

```
package textfiles;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class FileData {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String file_name = "C:/blabla";

        try {
            ReadFile file = new ReadFile(file_name);
            WriteFile data = new WriteFile(file_name, true);
            String[] aryLines = file.OpenFile();

            int i;
            int j;
            int y;

            for (i=0; i < aryLines.length; i++ ) { //goes through whole text file
                System.out.println( aryLines[ i ]);

                if (i == 0) {
                    data.writeToFile("");
                    System.lineSeparator();
                }

                char[] ch = aryLines[ i ].toCharArray();
                ArrayList<Character> num = new ArrayList<Character>();
                String xCo = null;


                boolean counterX = false;

                if ((ch[0]) == 'G' && ch[1] == '1') {

                    for (j = 0; j < ch.length; j++) { //goes through each line of text file

                        for (y = 0; counterX == true; y++) {
                            num.add(ch[j]);
                        }

                        if (ch[j] == 'X') {
                            counterX = true;
                        }

                        else if (ch[j] == ' ') {
                            counterX = false;
                        }
                    }
                    xCo = num.toString();
                    data.writeToFile("MOVX (" + xCo + ")");
                }
                num.clear();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
        }

        System.out.println("Text File Written To");

    }
}
```

Comment: How would `for (y = 0; counterX == true; y++) {` ever finish?

Comment: once the control is inside the flow `for (y = 0; counterX == true; y++)` All you are doing is adding the character in your num arraylist. It will be an endless loop as there is no terminating condition. `Since counterX should be false to end the loop But you have not assigned the same`

Comment: Basically, some of your nested loops are not nested enough.

Comment: Ah yeah that makes sense, I didn't realise I had the statement outside that loop. Cheers for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to avoid reading data into memory and to use streaming instead.
Then function which converts lines could look like:

```
    public void convertFile(String fileName, String tmpFileName) throws IOException {
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(tmpFileName, true)){
            Pattern pG1_X = Pattern.compile("^G1 X");
            Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(fileName)).lines().forEach(line -> {
                try {
                    double x = Double.parseDouble(pG1_X.split(line)[1]); // get coordinate
                    String newLine = String.format("MOVX(%f)\n",x);      // attempt to replace coordinate format
                    writer.write(newLine);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, String.format("error wile converting line %s", line), e);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Testcase which demonstrates how it works:

```
package com.github.vtitov.test;

import org.junit.experimental.theories.DataPoints;
import org.junit.experimental.theories.Theories;
import org.junit.experimental.theories.Theory;
import org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;

@RunWith(Theories.class)
public class ReadWriteTest {
    final static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ReadWriteTest.class.getName());

    public void convertFile(String fileName, String tmpFileName) throws IOException {
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(tmpFileName, true)){
            Pattern pG1_X = Pattern.compile("^G1 X");
            Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(fileName)).lines().forEach(line -> {
                try {
                    double x = Double.parseDouble(pG1_X.split(line)[1]); // get coordinate
                    String newLine = String.format("MOVX(%f)\n",x);      // attempt to replace coordinate format
                    writer.write(newLine);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, String.format("error wile converting line %s", line), e);
                }
            });
        }
    }


    @DataPoints static public Long[] fileSizes() {return new Long[]{100L,10_000L,1_000_000L}; }
    @Theory
    public void readWriteTest(Long fileSize) throws Exception {
        TemporaryFolder folder = TemporaryFolder.builder().parentFolder(new File("target")).build();
        folder.create();
        File file = folder.newFile(UUID.randomUUID() + ".txt");
        File tmpFile = folder.newFile(file.getName() + ".tmp");
        createFile(fileSize, file);
        String filePath = file.getPath();
        LOGGER.info(String.format("created file %s of %d lines", filePath, fileSize));
        String tmpFilePath = filePath + ".tmp";
        convertFile(filePath, tmpFilePath);
        LOGGER.info(String.format("file %s converted to %s", filePath, tmpFilePath));
        //assert false;
        Files.move(new File(tmpFilePath).toPath(), new File(filePath).toPath(),
                StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING, StandardCopyOption.ATOMIC_MOVE);
        LOGGER.info(String.format("file %s moved to %s", tmpFilePath, filePath));
        folder.delete();
    }

    private void createFile(long fileSize, File file) throws Exception {
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file,true)) {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            rnd.doubles(fileSize).forEach(l -> {
                try { writer.write(String.format("G1 X%f\n", l)); } catch (IOException ignored) {}
            });
        }
    }

}
```